# Qemu & AIX 6.1 - what am i missing?

Tags: fedora, virtualbox, aix, qemu

I have a Fedora 14 i386 / T7100 C2D HP notebook. I need to run e.g.: AIX 6.1 on it for testing purposes.

I installed a VirtualBox on this Fedora machine. I installed a guest os in the VirtualBox. It's again, a Fedora 14 :P

Ok! here comes the fun part:

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=aixtest.img bs=1 count=1 seek=4294967292
qemu-system-ppc -prom-env 'auto-boot?=true' -hda aixtest.img -m 512 -cdrom aix61/IBM.AIX.v6.1-XXXXXXXX-DVD1.iso -boot d
```

But the only thing I see is this:

http://img251.imageshack.us/img251/7103/whereis.png

A couple of new lines created (before i type "test-all" command) and i can't see the aix installer :O<

How could I install/run a fresh version of AIX in e.g. Qemu? Is it possible? Or e.g.: only AIX ~2 will boot only?

Comment: Background: [How to run a fresh version of AIX in a Virtual Machine with a Linux host?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/10408/how-to-run-a-fresh-version-of-aix-in-a-virtual-machine-with-a-linux-host) (@johnny8888: you should have mentioned that in your question). While this isn't a duplicate, I doubt the non-duplicate part can be answered here. Qemu just isn't emulating the hardware AIX expects.

Comment: nobody has ideas about this? :\

Comment: Is it not solved? There's a self-answer that's accepted; if you're still having a problem you should probably unaccept it

Answer (score -2, accepted):

There is no way that i could run a fresh version of AIX (in a virtual machine) on my i386 / T7100 C2D HP notebook.

Comment: @johhn8888 how does this improve upon the answer given by @pdo ? I'm not particularly sure why you answered this instead of accepting his answer.

Comment: I assume it's just misunderstanding how accepts work. This isn't like a forum where you need to reply with how you fixed something -- if someone's answer worked for you, you can just accept it directly. The only time you should need to post your own answer is if none of the existing answers cover everything

Answer (score 4):

Not sure what more you can do; according to http://www.claunia.com/qemu/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=305 AIX 6.1 will not install under QEMU.

Comment: Any other versions on any other virtualization? No? :(