# What is the cheapest way to run AIX 6-7 at home?

Tags: aix

What is the cheapest way to run AIX 6-7 at home?
Using an emulator or is there any low-cost hardware that can run AIX6 or AIX7?

Purpose: practicing VIO/LPAR/HMC/etc..

Comment: Very related: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/10408/how-to-run-a-fresh-version-of-aix-in-a-virtual-machine-with-a-linux-host. In short, that's not practically possible at home. Even less so if you want VIOs. HMC is another thing altogether, but that could probably be virtualized (runs on x86, SDMC is available as VMWare images too)

Comment: FYI - you can get cheap (relatively) used POWER boxes. Specifically, you can look for POWER5+ systems, for example, p505,p510, which are low-power options that *should* run the latest versions of AIX6/7. HMC is not yet virtualized, so you could look into using IVM (integrated virtualization manager) if you wanted to virtualize your LPARs.