# I want to try out AIX in my pc, can i emulate it or get it to run for a very affordable price?

Tags: aix, qemu

can AIX be emulated with QEMU or can i buy an old IBM processor to use it? or some other easy way?

Comment: your best bet is to find a POWER system with AIX already installed and buy that.  I doubt you'll find AIX affordable, but you'll have to talk to IBM about pricing to find out.

Comment: Related: http://serverfault.com/questions/275294/cheap-n-easy-aix-hosting-services

Answer (score 2):

AIX VMs are available in the cloud:

- https://www.siteox.com/store/ibm-aix-lpars
- [lparbox.com (now defunct)](https://web.archive.org/web/20210224020818/https://lparbox.com/)

Comment: it seems IBM also supports [AIX on cloud](https://www.ibm.com/mysupport/s/topic/0TO0z0000006MVQGA2/aix-on-cloud?language=en_US)

Answer (score 2):

You have the following options:

First keep in mind that AIX is a commercial OS, and you need to purchase a license from IBM to use it and get updates.

**Option 1: I want to learn/use AIX at home.**

Buy an old Power5 Workstation; it is not too expensive (400$-800$) and can run AIX 6.1 or better AIX 7.1, but not VIOS (a sort of "AIX" which can run other AIX partitions, like hp-ux vpars, or vmware-esxi VM's).

This is a nice solution, but you will run only one OS.

**Option 2: I want to use AIX and admin it.**

Buy a Power7 or Power8 server, they are noisy and really expensive (over 7000$), but you can run VIOS or PowerVC (a very nice cloud similar to OpenStack wich can run AIX and Linux partitions on a Power7 server from a RHEL 6.5 HOST).

This is the better solution to learn to administrate more than one single machine.

**Note**: even VIOS and PowerVC are commercial products (and RHEL 6.5 too).

Answer (score 1):

Grab a 43P off ebay for about $200. I have one here I use to support some of my older RS/6000 installs.

Comment: What currency are you using? $ covers a lot of bases; USD perhaps?

Answer (score 1):

Seems partly like a duplicate of [What is the cheapest way to run AIX 6-7 at home?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/91976/what-is-the-cheapest-way-to-run-aix-6-7-at-home) and [How to run a fresh version of AIX in a Virtual Machine with a Linux host?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/10408/how-to-run-a-fresh-version-of-aix-in-a-virtual-machine-with-a-linux-host)

Also, at http://www.polarhome.com/ you can get root shell for AIX for as low as 10€/month.

And as far as I'm aware, emulation of anything more recent then AIX 3 or 4 is not possible currently.