# Difference between AIX and other Unix flavours

Tags: aix, virtualization, powerpc

I am learning AIX 6-7 for practice, is there any alternative unix flavour which could be quite similar to AIX which could be run on a VMWare or Virtualbox for practice? Also, if there is any possibility of running AIX on your laptop, please let me know. I was also looking fot options through using Qemu for simulating Power systems.

Comment: virtually a duplicate of http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/10408/22565

Comment: Could this be better answered on the [Software Recommendations](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/) site?

Answer (score 0):

The vast majority of features in AIX which differ significantly from other UNIXes are related to the hardware on which it runs.

As such, in my view, there's little point learning how to use AIX without learning that in conjunction with the hardware, even if it was possible (which it pretty much isn't).

If you can administer another flavour of UNIX, moving to AIX is all about the differences in hardware, much the same as moving from Linux to HP-UX would be.  Sure, there are some minor differences on the standard UNIX commands, but in general those differences are small.

The biggest area of difference overall, in my view, is AIX's management of storage (LVM) which is second to none as far as I'm concerned.